# jQuery animation delay on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm coding some jQuery to animate all the .linkbox to increase in height and it works great except that the element that I'm clicking on is slower than the other two elements (so it's like it's slower on hover), how do I make all the three elements animate the exact same way, shouldn't they already do that? Also they are animating from the bottom is it possible to tell it to animate it from the top?

Here's a link with all the code: http://jsbin.com/fihes/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Thanks in advance!

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="linkbox"><div class="text">Om mig</div></div>
    <div class="linkbox"><div class="text">Portfolio</div></div>
    <div class="linkbox"><div class="text">Kontakt</div></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background:black;
background-attachment:fixed;
width: 102%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.linkbox{
opacity: 0.5;
width:33%;
height: 200px;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 0px;
margin: -2px;
display:inline-block;
margin-top: 35%;    
}

.linkbox:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;

}

.text{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 42px;
    padding: 74px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.linkbox').click(function(){
    $('.linkbox').animate({height:"400px"}, "slow", "swing");
});
$('.text').click(function(){
    $('.text').fadeTo("fast", 0);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click code is slower because you have `"slow"` , you can change it to `"fast"` instead, like so:

```
$('.linkbox').click(function(){
    $('.linkbox').animate({height:"400px"}, "fast", "swing");
});
```

To answer your second question, I don't believe it's possible with just `.animate()` to have it slide from the top down. However, there is the `.slideDown()` effect.

> The .slideDown() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide down, making way for the
>   revealed items

http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: The only thing that it does is making all the animations faster. The thing is that the div that I'm clicking on is slower in the animation than the other two divs, so if I'm clicking the middle div the divs next to that div have completed their animations when the middle div is halfway through its animation.

Comment: well, you can change the other ones to "slow" , or you can use time in miliseconds .. like 5000 , which would be 5 seconds

Comment: How do I do that? I only have that snippet of code, shouldn't all the three divs have the same animation speed already?